# Should I include a photo on my resume?

Tags: resume, career-development, united-states

I am curious about average opinion on this, what do people think about a small headshot photo on a paper resume?

Comment: Please add a country tag. Having a photo in your application is somewhere between required format and weird and unnecessary. Please do not pick an answer here without a country mentioned. There are no global CV requirements. Handing in one countries perfect CV in in another country will only lead to it being thrown into the bin.

Comment: Unless you're a model/actor trying to get into a commercial/TV show/movie, or maybe applying to be cabin crew for an airline- **NO!!** Employers care about what you can do,  not what you look like

Comment: `what do people think about a small headshot photo on a paper resume?` - Why would you want to? It has no relevance, is superfluous, and is unnecessary.

Comment: @HorusKol police applications asks for a photo

Answer (score 6):

Not needed. CVs get photocopied etc. Just wastes space with a picture of something that looks like the backside of a bungulow.

Comment: “Backend of a bus” is also a common term...

Answer (score 2):

Take a coin and decide heads or tails... some places want a photo, others are not worried either way and some prefer not to have a photo...

Depends on the business or industry - hospitality likes to have photos on cv’s...